# JavaScript not validating form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

For some reason my JavaScript won't validate my forms and I cannot work out why. I've followed examples from many sites like Tizag & W3C, but to no avail.

HTML form:

```
<form class='login' name='login' onsubmit='return loginValidation();' method='post' action='index.php'>
    <p>
       <input class='login' type='text' name='nameentry'/><br/>
       <input class='login' type='submit' value='Login'/>
    </p>

</form>
```

JavaScript function:

```
    function loginValidation(){
    var x=document.form.login.nameentry.value;
    if(x==null || x==""){
        alert("Enter a name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

My code can be seen in action [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/gij2/cs25010/) [an assignment]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unclosed function (or for block) which is killing the engine:

```
function testAllQuantity(){
    for(i=0;i<150,i++){
      quantityValidation(document.getElementById(i));
    }
```

And the for statement is misformed, `,` -> `;`

```
for(i=0;i<150;i++){
```

Comment: Those validation functions were works in progress, never considered that they could be the problem as I assumed it would only use the one in question, thanks!

Comment: Cheers for the advice with that loop too :)

Answer (score 2):

Second line in function should be

```
var x=document.forms.login.nameentry.value;
```

Comment: I've changed it & the results are no different.